# How can I get the price of the other table

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a table `products`:

```
Products
-id
-seller_id
-category_id
-product_name
```

and also a `Product_options` table:

```
Product_options 
-id
-product_id
-size_name
-width
-height
-quantity
-price
```

I have here a function `show` which is a function where you can view the products in home.blade.php:

```
public function show($id)
{  
    $likes = DB::SELECT(DB::RAW("SELECT count(*) as like_count FROM `likes` WHERE product_id = $id"));

    $products = DB::SELECT(DB::RAW("SELECT p.id as product_id, p.name as product_name, p.price, p.description, p.image, c.id as category_id, c.name as category_name FROM products p, categories c WHERE p.category_id = c.id AND p.id = $id"));

    $product_options = DB::SELECT(DB::RAW("SELECT po.pricee FROM product_options po, products p WHERE p.id = po.product_id AND product_id = $product_id "));

    return View::make('products.show', ['products' => $products, 'like_count' => $likes[0]->like_count,'product_options'=>$product_options]);
```

Home.blade.php

```
if(isset($products) && $products) {
    foreach ($products as $product => $value) {

        $new_description = strlen($products[$product]->description) > 50 ? substr($products[$product]->description,0,50)."..." : $products[$product]->description;

        echo '
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail" >
                    <div class="pull-right">';
                        if(Auth::check()) {
                            if(Auth::user()->id == $products[$product]->seller_id) {
                                echo '<a href="'.URL::to('product/editproduct', [$products[$product]->product_id]).'">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                                </a>';

                            }
                            else {
                                echo '<a href="">&nbsp;</a>';
                            }
                        }

                        echo    '</div><a href="'.URL::route('categories', [$products[$product]->category_name]).'"><h4 class="text-center"><span class="label label-info">'.$products[$product]->category_name.'</span></h4></a>

                            <div class="img-container-background">
                                <div class="img-container">

                                    <a href="'.URL::to('product/'.$products[$product]->product_id).'"> <img src="'.URL::asset('assets/images/uploads/'.$products[$product]->image).'" class="img-responsive" /></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="caption">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                        <h3 style="font-size:20px">'.$products[$product]->product_name.'</h3>
<span>By <a href="">'.$products[$product]->seller_name.'</a></span>
```

How I can get the price of `product_options` to view the price in my home blade?

Comment: did you notice the typo? `SELECT po.pricee` shouldn't it be `SELECT po.price`

Comment: Arayt. I already did the same but nothing happens. Can't get the price of the product_options table :/ @davejal

Comment: Just a tip: Stop using old-style JOINs see [this blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) , not that it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this in your controller:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
->join('product_options', 'products.id', '=', 'product_options.product_id')
->get();

return View::make('products.show')
    ->withProducts($products);
```

Let the Query Builder do all the hard work for you instead of writing out all of your queries, then all you have to do is loop through your $products variable in your home blade and you should be set.